# how to get every 4th month of registration date till today

Tags: php

I have this php code that i m trying to finish. 
It need to know every 4th month from registration until today.

Code:

```
$date = '2016-12-23';
$dateRegistered = '2016-01-08';

$d1b = strtotime($date);
$d2b = strtotime($dateRegistered);
$min_dateb = min($d1b, $d2b);
$max_dateb = max($d1b, $d2b);
//echo $min_dateb.' - '.$max_dateb;
$Tb = 0;
//$getwwy=null;
while (($min_dateb = strtotime("+1 MONTH", $min_dateb)) <= $max_dateb) {
    $Tb++;

}
//echo $Tb;
```

i get returned numbers from 1-10 now.

it should be 4, 8, 12, . .. and so on

then i want it to see the match

```
$datem =  date("m", strtotime($date));
if($datem==$Tb){
//echo '<td>echo some result</td>'; 
}
```

Comment: Does it need to be 4, 8, 12? Every 4 months means 5 and 9 to me (and 1 from next year).

Comment: @Blaatpraat I m confused now about that!But i think for that i only should edit 1 number in code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$dateRegistered = new DateTime('2016-01-08');
$now = new DateTime();
$quarters = array();

while ($dateRegistered->format('n') <= $now->format('n') && $dateRegistered < $now) {

    if ($dateRegistered->format('n') % 4 === 0) {
        $quarters[] = clone $dateRegistered;
    }

    $dateRegistered->modify('+1 month');
}

var_dump($quarters);
```

If you need only the months number then you can use array_map, or you can simply add only the months number in the quarters array in the while loop

```
$quarters = array_map(function($date) {
    return $date->format('n');
}, $quarters);

var_dump($quarters);
```

Comment: YES this thing works  thank you :) but just one more question :D teach this noob how to use this array in if statement?

Comment: If you want to use it directly in the while loop then you don't need that array anymore.. just use the $dateRegistered variable to do what you want

Comment: if i use it in while loop it echos new <td> * result in in loop :(

Comment: Actually found it not working when i go to next year: example 2016-10-18 to 2017-01-01

Comment: And if registration date is 2016-10-18 then it shows 12 on December but it should not be that way